# Millisecond time: Filter form by date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to implement millisecond timestamping in Access 2010/13 using this method; 
[MS Access Can Handle Millisecond Time Values--Really - See more at:](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046)

The Millisecond value is queried by; 
`SELECT DateValueMsec([DateTimeMs]) AS DateOnly FROM` - to provide a date only control to sort the form from a textbox.
Any filter applied programmatically on DateOnly yeilds 0 results.

```
Private Sub BuildFilter()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim ctl As Control

    strFilter = ""

'add selected values to string
    For Each ctl In Me.FormHeader.Controls
        With ctl
            If .ControlType = acTextBox Or .ControlType = acComboBox Then
                If Nz(.Value) <> "" Then
                    If InStr(.Name, "Date") <> 0 Then
                        If Nz(StartDate) <> "" And Nz(EndDate) <> "" And InStr(strFilter, "DateOnly") = 0 Then
                            strFilter = strFilter & "[DateOnly] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate.Value & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate.Value & "# AND "
                        ElseIf Nz(StartDate) <> "" And InStr(strFilter, "DateOnly") = 0 Then
                       strFilter = strFilter & "[DateOnly] >= #" & DateValueMsec(Me.StartDate.Value) & "# AND "
                     '       strFilter = strFilter & "[DateOnly] >= #" & Me.StartDate.Value & "# AND "
                        ElseIf Nz(EndDate) <> "" And InStr(strFilter, "DateOnly") = 0 Then
                            strFilter = strFilter & "[DateOnly] <= #" & Me.EndDate.Value & "# AND "
                        End If
                    ElseIf InStr(.Name, "ID") <> 0 Then
                        strFilter = strFilter & "[" & .Name & "] = " & .Value & " AND "
                    Else
                        strFilter = strFilter & "[" & .Name & "] = '" & .Value & "' AND "
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ctl
'trim trailing
    strFilter = TrimR(strFilter, 5)

Debug.Print strFilter
    With Me.subfrmzzAuditTrailDisplay
        .Form.Filter = strFilter
        .Form.FilterOn = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried different data types;
If Queried value and filter are **Dates**; the result is 0
If **String** the result is All
When the filter is applied

Answer (score 0):

Answer! From @pathDongle

Time is stored as Millisecond UTC;

```
!DateTimeMS = GetTimeUTC()
```

And restored by;

```
Public Function UTCtoTimeLocal(dSysUTC As Date) As Date
'Dim sysTime As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim DST As Long
    Dim tzi As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION

    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(tzi)
    UTCtoTimeLocal = dSysUTC - TimeSerial(0, tzi.Bias, 0) + IIf(DST = 2, TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Query;

```
SELECT tblzzAuditTrail.DateTimeMS, FormatDate(UTCtoTimeLocal([DateTimeMS])) AS DateTimeLocal
```

Which can be filtered on as a String.

```
Private Sub BuildFilter()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim ctl As Control

    strFilter = ""

'add selected values to string
    For Each ctl In Me.FormHeader.Controls
        With ctl
            If .ControlType = acTextBox Or .ControlType = acComboBox Then
                If Nz(.Value) <> "" Then
                    If InStr(.Name, "Date") <> 0 Then
                        If Nz(StartDate) <> "" And Nz(EndDate) <> "" And InStr(strFilter, "DateTimeLocal") = 0 Then
                            strFilter = strFilter & "[DateTimeLocal] BETWEEN '" & FormatDate(Me.StartDate.Value) & "' AND '" & FormatDate(Me.EndDate.Value) & "' AND "
                        ElseIf Nz(StartDate) <> "" And InStr(strFilter, "DateTimeLocal") = 0 Then
                            strFilter = strFilter & "[DateTimeLocal] > '" & FormatDate(Me.StartDate.Value) & "' AND "
                        ElseIf Nz(EndDate) <> "" And InStr(strFilter, "DateTimeLocal") = 0 Then
                            strFilter = strFilter & "[DateTimeLocal] <= '" & FormatDate(Me.EndDate.Value) & "' AND "
                        End If
                    ElseIf InStr(.Name, "ID") <> 0 Then
                        strFilter = strFilter & "[" & .Name & "] = " & .Value & " AND "
                    Else
                        strFilter = strFilter & "[" & .Name & "] = '" & .Value & "' AND "
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ctl
'trim trailing And
    strFilter = TrimR(strFilter, 5)

Debug.Print strFilter
    With Me.subfrmzzAuditTrailDisplay
        .Form.Filter = strFilter
        .Form.FilterOn = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Resulting Filter String;

```
[UserID] = 2 AND [DateTimeLocal] BETWEEN '06/01/2015 00:00:00.000' AND '07/01/2015 00:00:00.000'
```

As per my other question;

[millisecond-time-msec2-incorrect-return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816493/millisecond-time-msec2-incorrect-return)